# Change default document 'edit' tool in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, text-editors

I tried to change the default text EDITING tool from notepad to notepad++, but for whatever reason it doesn't work.
Note, that I DON'T want to make notepad++ the default program to open these kind of files. Thats a different issue. I want it to open when you rightclick a .txt file and click on 'edit'.

I've written a little .reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\document\shell\edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

The .reg file works alright, the value is changed. However, when rightclicking a .txt file and clicking 'edit', instead of opening the file in notepad++, Windows just opens the file dialog, asking me whether I want to continue opening this type of file with Notepad++ (which is already preselected).

What do I do wrong, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved the issue myself. Turned out you have to change the key in

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command]
```

Comment: and under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell` one can delete or change the `edit` entry and get rid of this default `Edit` entry in any picture contextual menu, calling Paint 3D instead of your preferred application.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, mine worked when I changed this Windows registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command
```

From:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

To:

```
%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\NightRise.NotepadWrapped_7.59.32.0_x64__bahp16nyyek9m\Notepad++.exe %1
```

Note, my Notepad++ installation was from the Windows Store, and I suspect the last portion of the path might differ on a different Windows 10 machine.

I found the exact path for Notepad++.exe by going to Windows task manager, right clicking the Notepad++ item, then selecting "Open File Location"

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Adding this from a Github because it's hard to find.., expanding on what Simmen mentioned.

```
https://gist.github.com/ma-al/6a70a55dca30f9e3d1cc473a43c87ec3
```

For Windows 10, to change the bat/ini/cmd "edit" context menu (right click, edit) change these keys in regedit:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\edit\command
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cmdfile\shell\edit\command
```

From: `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1` to:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1"
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
"%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
 %ProgramFiles%{insert-path-to-fave-editor}" "%1"
```

The OP also says replace this one as well. I did not and it works fine, but I also tried replacing it and it did not replace the association so I have no clue what it does so, here it sits for reference.

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\open\command
```

Comment: lol. Here I am 8 months later, needing this setting and would you look at that. I was the one to post the solution. Nice.

Comment: Another year and a half later, here I am. If you are on windows 11 and this is NOT working, it is because of the new W11 Notepad2. Just go to programs and uninstall Notepad.. Idk how to make them both work together, but this fixed it.